# Who is a Gandhabbha?

Tags: pali-canon, pali-language

Are gandhabbhas belongs to gods or demons? I tried to find details about them. But couldn't solve my problem. According to the Buddhas Teachings, I want to know whether Gandhabbhas are divine people or evil people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A class of semi divine beings](http://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/gandhabba/index.html) who inhabit the [Catummaharajika](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html) realm and are the lowest among the devas. They are generally classed together with the Asuras and the Nagas. Beings are born among them as a result of having practised the lowest form of sila. They are said to be able to receive merits from humans.

Comment: May triple gem bless you! It's really helpful.

Comment: Theruwan Saranai!